# Overriding lifecycle hooks in Blazor razor file

Tags: blazor

I'm trying to make a component that will show the time elapsed from an origin DateTime.

As I understand, you can override some lifecycle methods in order to run some code when a component is initialized. But I'm getting a weird compiler error.

Here's the component in question, `Timer.cshtml`.

```
<div>
    <span>It has been @Elapsed.ToString() since @Origin.ToString().</span>
</div>

@functions {
    [Parameter]
    DateTime Origin { get; set; }

    TimeSpan Elapsed { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInit()
    {
        this.Elapsed = new TimeSpan(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks - Origin.Ticks);
    }
}
```

`dotnet run` shows a weird compiler error. `obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\Pages\Timer.g.cs(34,139): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\path_to_app\BlazorApp1\BlazorApp1.csproj]`

There's also this error in VSCode. Sounds like you have to create a backing Class to override lifecycle methods. Is that true? Is there a way to override lifecycle hooks in the Razor page?

Comment: you can definitely override lifecycle methods in a razor view and your code works for me perfectly when I tested it so I believe the cause of your error lies elsewhere. I'm calling the compenent exactly as you have it written via `<Timer Origin="DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)"></Timer>`

Comment: have you tried cleaning/rebuilding solution and opening/closing visual studio? also may want to try opening the file `Timer.g.cs` and finding the syntax error. that may help you hunt down the source of the error

Comment: Thanks. the problem did lay in just doing dumb stuff

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question of "can you override in Razor pages without a backing class?" is yes.